# generating Random numbers using rand()

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to generate a bunch of random numbers using rand() % (range). 
Here's how my code is setup :

```
srand(time(NULL));
someClass *obj = new someClass(rand()%range1,rand()%range2... etc ); // i.e. a number of random numbers one after the other
```

Whenever I run this, it seems all the calls to rand() generate the same number. I tried doing it without the : (edit : all rand() do not generate the same number it seems , read edit at the end)

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

then , every execution of the program yields the same results.

Also, since all calls to rand() are in a constructor , I cant really reseed it all the time. I guess I can create all objects sent to the constructor beforehand and reseed the random number generator in between, but it seems like an inelegant solution.

How can I generate a bunch of different random numbers ?

edit: It seems because I was creating a lot of objects in a loop, so every time the loop iterated srand(time(NULL)) was reseeded and the sequence got reset ( as time(NULL) has a resolution of a second) , that's why all subsequent objects had very similar properties.

Comment: Try using random_r http://www.ellipsix.net/blog/2009/3/how-to-use-random-r.html . That way you can seed once.

Comment: You should only be seeding the random number generator at the beginning. Could you post more of the code? It seems that you are saying that `rand()%range1 = rand()%range2 = ... = rang()%rangen`, but that shouldn't be the case. What are `range1` etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you call `srand` *once*, then all subsequent `rand` calls will return (different) pseudorandom numbers. If they don't, you're doing it wrong. :)

Apart from this, `rand` is pretty useless. Boost.Random (or the C++11 standard library `<random>` header) provides much more powerful random number generators, with nicer, more modern interfaces as well (for example allowing you to have multiple independent generators, unlike `rand` which uses a single global seed)

Comment: Not sure I'd agree with "`rand` is pretty useless".  The quality does vary, and applications which require a quality random number generator will have to look elsewhere, but `rand` is often sufficient for just playing around or experimenting.

Comment: When a better alternative is available, I'd argue that it's pretty hard to find a use for `rand`. Which, pretty much by definition, would make it useless. :)

Comment: You could say that for almost everything, then.  Better alternatives are available, but to use them generally means extra effort to find and install them.  If you're using random numbers for some real work, you'll probably do so; but for just playing around, there's no need.  Even for real work, if portability isn't an issue, and the implementation of `rand()` on your platform is sufficiently good, there's no point in searching another solution.

Comment: @JamesKanze: if something requires extra effort (to find and install), then it is not necessarily a better alternative. But when the standard library provides two random generators, a good one and a bad one, then the bad one is useless.

Comment: When the standard implemented by your compilers offers the choice, then yes.  Practically speaking, the "standard" you program against today is C++03, and will be for the next couple of years.

Answer (score 2):

Unless reseeded with a different starting point, `rand()` always returns the same sequence. That is actually a feature to make program tests repeatable!

So, you *have* to call `srand` if you want a different sequence for different runs. Perhaps you can do that before calling the first constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Call srand once at the begin of the program. Then call rand()%range any time you want a random number. Here is an example for your situation, that works pretty well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    Test(int num0,int num1, int num2):num0_(num0),num1_(num1),num2_(num2){}
    int num0_,num1_,num2_;
};

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    Test *test=new Test(rand()%100,rand()%100,rand()%100);
    cout << test->num0_ << "\n";
    cout << test->num1_ << "\n";
    cout << test->num2_ << "\n";
    delete test;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code at: http://ideone.com/xV0R3#view_edit_box

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int i=0;
srand(time(NULL));
while(i<10)
{
cout<<rand()<<endl;
i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

this produces different random numbers. you need to call `srand()` only once. rand() generates a different number every time after the `srand()` call

Comment: *No*. Just plain *no*. Calling `srand` more than once is very rarely useful outside of tests.

Comment: Don't you only need to call it once?